# Why does the LTC2068 op-amp fail as a buffer for a 13 MHz ADC?

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass, buffer

I am designing an AA LPF for my 8-bit ADC running at ~13.1 Msps, to sample a buffered differential signal. My goal is to down-sample this stream to 200 Hz, effectively increasing my ADC resolution to 16 bits.

I am planning to use a simple RC AA filter with cutoff at 16.6 kHz to give me a wide "unattenuated" passband and minimal phase lag on the analog domain. The output of this filter is then buffered before an ADC. The circuit is as follows:

[image]

Since my specs require low noise, low offset voltage, zero-drift, high accuracy signals, I thought the [LTC2066/7/8](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc2066-2067-2068.pdf) would be a good choice. However, simulations show that the buffered output is highly distorted:

[image]

What specs cause this? The GBP of the op-amp should be enough to drive this. Analog.com's Filter Wizard does not recommend this op-amp for my design due to its low output impedance which may be a clue, but I'm not 100% sure how this would affect my design.

Comment: DC voltage at the input (0V in the sim) is below the (common-mode) input voltage range.  This is not a rail-to-rail input opamp.

Comment: Even a rail-to-rail opamp wouldn't be able to output below GND signals... You need a negative supply, or level-shift your Signal

Comment: I don't need the full 0-5V range so I'm fine with a smaller headroom. Rohat's answer below highlights the fact that my input signal was actually -0.5V to 0.5V that caused the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your signal has no offset and cause the op amp's output to clip. Since the op amp is running with single supply it won't be able to handle negative inputs.

If you put a DC offset to your AC source and re-run the simulation everything will be fine:

[image]

NOTE: I put a 500k load because the op amp's gain and phase graphs are given for R<sub>L</sub> = 499k.